# facebook login with tabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to add a Facebook Login function on my app. However, somehow it gives an error saying "'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller  as a child of view controller:'
".
My app delegate is written as follow. Could anyone give me an advice how I could fix the problem?

AppDelegate.h

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) LoginViewController* loginViewController;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *mainViewController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    self.loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController"
                                                                   bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //mainwindow
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // ViewControllers array
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self resetMainViewController];

    //homeview
    self.mainViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    //adding navigation controller
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
    [viewControllers addObject:self.navigationController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //secondview
    SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    //adding navigation
    UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    [viewControllers addObject:navController2];

    // Thirdview
    ThirdViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    //adding navigationcontroller
    UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    [viewControllers addObject:navController3];

    //fourthview
    FourthViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    //adding navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    [viewControllers addObject:navController4];

    //fifthviewcontroller
    FifthViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];
    //adding navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];
    [viewControllers addObject:navController5];


    //tabbarcontroller
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thank you.

Comment: all the code above is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Comment: Yes, they are all in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: i think you should remove all other self.window.rootViewController assignment. the last one is enough.

Comment: when i removed the other self.window.rootViewController assignment, the error disappeared, but my loginViewController does not appear.

Comment: you'd better optimize your view hierarchy, it's a bit messy

Comment: your loginViewController is lost, because you initialize self.navigationController again after you initialize with loginViewController.

Comment: You want all the view controllers in one tabBarController, also the loginViewController?

Comment: I want all the view controllers in one tabBarController, but would like to show the loginViewController only when you login.

Comment: you can consider add the loginViewController to as the root of the self.navigationController. self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController. then when you do some operation in the loginViewController, push self.tabBarController to show it, which means init the self.tabBarController not here, maybe in the loginViewController methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `self.navigationController` to `self.window.rootViewController` at the beginning, then add it to the `viewcontrollers` of the `self.tabBarController`, this is the problem. You should remove all other `self.window.rootViewController` assignments, and remain the last one.